# Is there any reason to turn off auto-equip?

Tags: soda-dungeon

*Soda Dungeon* sees you recruiting adventures to explore a dungeon. The game works by providing you with a Tavern you upgrade. Tavern upgrades draw better adventurers, so you can go deeper into the dungeon, etc.

Since you're constantly recruiting new adventurers and gaining new equipment, manually equipping everyone is a pain. There's an option in-game to automatically equip your current heroes with the beat gear you have - is there any reason NOT to use this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generally it's fine to auto-equip. There are some exceptions, however - as you progress and unlock different adventurers and obtain different gear, sometimes what the game auto-equips is not necessarily the most ideal. For spell casting classes you'll want to focus more on skill damage and MP recovery/boosters. Sometimes you might want a run through decked out in as much gold and item rarity boosters as you can.

There is an option (that I believe you must unlock from the shop) that allows you to save loadouts on a per-class basis. This tends to work out best, but I seem to recall it not taking into account better versions of the same equipment.

Also, as you get more relics and improve things like base crit chance, it may make some weapons more reliable, and better choices than the auto-equip gives them credit for.